# What does "Minütchen" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've heard the word "Minütchen" being used before verbally, in cases where I though using "Minute" would suffice. Is there a difference between the two? The former is the diminutive form of the latter, but I don't see the difference – a minute is always a minute, nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: It's pretty much used in the same way as _little minute_ in English. ("'ll have that done for you in a little minute.")

Comment: Eine Minute dauert 60 Sekunden, ein Minütchen 60 Sekündchen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do NOT totally agree with DJCrashdummy and therefor write my own answer:

First of all **Minütchen** is the diminutive of Minute and is used to play down the real time span that something lasts.

Lets take the following dialogue:

> Person 1: Do you really need me to wait until you're done?
> Person 2: Come on, it will just take a little minute
>
> Person 1: Soll ich wirklich warten, bis Du (endlich) fertig bist?
> Person 2: Komm schon, es dauert doch nur ein **Minütchen**!

In that case it is clear, that it will last more than a minute, until person 2 is really done, but wants to downplay and appease person 1 who is waiting.

So this is a little different from the other answer, as a **Minütchen** will not be less but rather more then one minute.

Comment: that's why i pointed out two different cases: sometimes it is used for a inaccurate time span; and on the other hand it is also used to downplay the real time span. -- this does not exclude the combination of both (like in your case).

Comment: sorry, I personally never heard someone use Minütchen as "less than a minute"... But that might be me... And in the first version of your answer I did not realise your second point to mean "downplay". Like it is now, your answer is more complete, but as I said: I personally don't know your first usage...

Answer (score 2):

Well... from the technical point of view you are right: a minute is a minute and that's it.

On the other hand you can say from a linguistic point of view that there is a difference and it is used in different settings:

- **Inaccurate time span:**
  "Minütchen" is sometimes used if you (hope/assume to) need less than a whole minute for something and/or you can't/won't be completely exact.
- **Downplay the real time span:**
  also this diminutive form is used (sometimes as plural) to ask for the time of other people, if you want to express it less time than it really is.
- **It is for sure also possible to combine this two cases.**

Comment: Bottom line: It’s a mere diminutive of *Minute* and can easily be synonym for a significantly prolonged period of time.